# how to get calculator to accept new numbers after equal sign is pressed? java

Tags: java

i am doing an exercise to create a simple calculator in java. 
i want the calculator to keep taking numbers after the equal sign is pressed. so if i press "10+10 =" the result will be 20, and if I want to press "+1 = " and the result will be 21. or if I want to subtract as well.
my code is below. im sure the change has to be made to the "equals" portion of the code but i am unsure where/how to begin.

```
public int getDisplayValue()
{
    return displayValue;
}

public void numberPressed(int number)
{

    currentValue = (currentValue * 10) + number;
    displayValue = currentValue;

}


private void applyPreviousOperation()
{
    if (previousOp == '+')
    {
        heldValue = heldValue + currentValue;
        displayValue = heldValue;
    }
        else if (previousOp == '-')
        {
            heldValue = heldValue - currentValue;
        displayValue = heldValue;
        }

            else {
            heldValue = currentValue;
        }

    }


public void plus()
{
   applyPreviousOperation();
   previousOp = '+'; 
   currentValue = 0;
}


public void minus()
{
     applyPreviousOperation();
   previousOp = '-'; 
   currentValue = 0;




}


public void equals()
{
    applyPreviousOperation();
    previousOp = ' ';

    currentValue = 0;
    heldValue = 0;
}


public void clear()
{
    displayValue = 0;
    previousOp = ' ';

}
```

}

Comment: What is expected when input is "2+3*4" ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your question more clearly.
what's the calculator flow should be. You describe an operation that contradicts a simple a+b.

It really matters how you input the numbers, If for example the very first operation is texted "a+b" ,"a-b" .... than you can keep it as currentValue.
than next opperations will be calculated against currentValue.

Answer (score 0):

Have a variable called defaultOperand.  When the equals button is pressed, update the defaultOperand variable with the output of the operation.  It becomes the default left side operand.  If an operation is inputted without a left side operand, then use the value in the defaultOperand as the default left hand operand.